# How to manage distinct node.js apps running at a VPS?

Tags: node.js, vps

I have multiple **`node.js`** apps running at my VPS, and I access to it through ssh. Right now I start them in the way:

```
nohup node server.js
```

That looks good but I get whole logs to `nohup.out`, and what's more important and not efficient is about restarting of stopping them.

If I do **`ps -A | grep node`** I will get an output like:

```
 9172 ?        00:00:01 node
 9178 ?        00:00:00 node
 ...
```

So, how can I identify them?

I also knew about **[nodemon](http://nodemon.io/)** and it's great! But however logging out ssh breaks the magic.

I think maybe some more advanced tools would help out. What's the best approach for this?

Just in case, I use Nginx on top (port 80) and do reverse proxy, but I'd be ok changing that.

Comment: I'd recommend switching to using [forever cli](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) for managing your processes. the whole question is literally becomes a no-brainer with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (there are many) is pm2: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

It's a process manager for node, and comes with a variety of features, some of which include the ability to spread your app across multiple CPU cores while providing an easy TTY management view of the applications.  It also has the ability to reload the apps without stopping them.

If the readme's not sufficient, I found this post useful in understanding the basics: http://devo.ps/blog/2013/06/26/goodbye-node-forever-hello-pm2.html

Comment: Thanks! So I'd bind my whole apps and sites to pm2 and it would admin them all? Or tracks for node processes? Does it matter if I have Nginx on top as my edit tells?

Comment: If you choose to use pm2, you'll want to start your apps using pm2 rather than node directly (or nodemon).  From there pm2 will handle starting/stopping/reloading as well as logs and other monitoring.  Nginx would not factor into this, since it would still send requests to the port you have running the node process.  I would try testing it out small first, just to see how it works.

Comment: Sure I will, thanks and welcome to SO. Btw do you manage any blog?

Comment: I wish so much SO had more of contact possibilities :P

Answer (score 1):

You can run nodemon under `--quiet` mode and it'll suppress all nodemon output (and keep your logging working).